# If I could, should I buy a car with cash instead of credit?

Tags: savings, credit

The most common (and realistically feasible) method of buying a car is to buy it with a loan/credit card, then pay it off in bits every time interval.

However, say that I could buy a car in full when I've fully decided that I should buy a car. Should I? Of course you will save up on interest that would have cost you a lot otherwise, but am I missing anything? Are there any disadvantages to buying big items in full?

Take note that this question doesn't only apply to cars. It applies to big things in general.

Answer (score 5):

If you have enough money to buy a car in full, that probably means you have good credit. If you have good credit, car dealerships will often offer 0% loans for either a small period of time, like 12 months, or the entire loan.

Taking a 0% loan is obviously more optimal than paying the entire lump sum up front. You can take the money and invest in other things that earn you more than 0%.

However, most dealerships offer a rebate OR a 0% loan. Some commenters below claim that the rebate is usually larger than the saved interest, so definitely do the math if you have that option.

Comment: On the other hand, those 0% loans often come with the tradeoff of a higher price on the car -- they have to earn their profit somewhere. Always negotiate price of the car first, ***THEN*** discuss whether dealer financing makes sense. Also, there's the peace-of-mind factor of not having to worry about when payments are due or when the 0% period might end. What is theoretically financially optimal, and what is optimal in practice, are not always the same thing.

Comment: Except that almost always if they'll offer you 0% financing they'll also offer a rebate if you don't take the 0%.  The only time I've seen cheap financing without rebates is with the Saturn--and that was because they never modified the asking price, period.

Comment: In many cases it saves money to take the rebate from the dealer and get a loan from a Credit Union. Frequently the rebate is bigger than the interest. To do this you need to arrange for the loan before going to the dealer.

Comment: All good comments. I incorporated them into my answer, thanks.

Comment: In the Netherlands, car companies are legally required to warn you that lending money costs money - even if they offer a "0% interest". The reason is exactly as stated: It's accounted for elsewhere.

Comment: +1   getting a 0% loan is great for cases when buying the car with cash will leave you with little wiggle money. Paying for it slowly will make sure you still have 'emergency' money and aren't broke all at once.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule of thumb, and assuming you have a choice, my advice is to pay cash for things things that depreciate, expenses, and consumables. Consider credit (even if you have cash) for things that will appreciate in value or generate cash flow. That is, use credit as leverage.

Comment: These days, I hesitate to assert that houses will increase in value. We've recently seen major counterexamples.

Comment: I can't think of any scenario where credit is superior to cash.

Comment: Good point. editing answer

Comment: What do you mean `use credit as leverage`? I'm sorry, I don't quite understand.

Comment: For example, I bought an investment property on credit (even though I had the cash) which I am renting out with positive cash flow. Essentially I am using someone else's money to make money. That frees up my cash for other profitable endeavors or as collateral to borrow more money. This enables me to invest more than I have. This is what I mean  by leverage.

Comment: I see. I understand now. So the best approach would be to use credit and pay as minimally as I can so that I would incur the least possible interest (or even 0%), so that I would be able to use my money for other things which would gain me returns. Correct?

Comment: The opposite. Use cash for a car since it won't create cash flow and will only depreciate in value. In fact, @LorenPechtel is probably right for 99% of the circumstances. Almost always use cash as your first option unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: I see. So is the issue here, mainly, inflation? Money not spent is money losing spending power due to inflation. Is that what you mean @JohnFx? So it would be good to spend that fixed amount in cash for a specific product, because tomorrow it would cost me a little more?

Comment: The advice makes sense because revenue-generating collateral decreases risk for the lender.